# how to change legend font size of FacetGrid plot?

Tags: python, seaborn

I am trying to plot histogram using sns.displot() with hue. I am trying to adjust legend size of each histogram using ax.get_legend() or plt.legend(). It tells me there is no handle for legend for facegrid. Here is the plot. Thanks

```
g=sns.displot(data,x=x,kind='hist', fill=True, hue=hue,palette=sns.color_palette('bright')[:4], height=15, aspect=1.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using `ax.get_legend()` directly? Because, if you are using `FacetGrid` OR `FactorPlot`. Then we have to use `plt.setp()` for **Setting Properties** of `Plot`. The `Format` for the same would be `plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='12')`. Hope this help you. Please can you try this `Snippet`?

Comment: Thanks Jay. Yes I did try  plt.setp(axis.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize=fontsize-4), and it didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the legend from the `FacetGrid` that `sns.displot` returns with `FacetGrid.legend`. Then you can modify the text elements like so:

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")

g = sns.displot(data=tips, x="total_bill", hue="day")

# Legend title
g.legend.get_title().set_fontsize(20)

# Legend texts
for text in g.legend.texts:
    text.set_fontsize(20)
```

[image: displot with larger legend text]